# How to update the total price of an item according to its quantity?

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I am developing a shopping cart website. On my cart page, the total price of an item should be updated as per the quantity of that item.  *https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart* I installed this shopping cart package.

How can I update the total price of an item according to its quantity?

**CartController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
use Darryldecode\Cart\Cart;

class CartController extends Controller
{
   
    public function index()
    {
       // $cartItems = \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();
        
         return view ('cart');
     }
   

    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
       
        return view('cart')->with(compact('product'));
   }


    public function update($rowId)
    {

        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->update($rowId, [
            'quantity' => [
            'relative' => true, 
            'value'=> request('quantity')
            ]
            ]);
        return back();
        
    }


    public function destroy($itemId)
    {

        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->remove($itemId);
        
        return back();
        
    }

    public function addtocart(Product $product)
    {
    
        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->add(array(
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->prod_name,
            'price' => $product->prod_price,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'attributes' => array(),
            'associatedModel' => $product
                 ));
                
                 return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

**cart.blade.php**

```
                        @foreach(\Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent() as $items)
                            <tr>
                            <form class="mb-4" action="{{route('cart.update',$items->id)}}">    
                            
                                <td data-title="Product">
                                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $items ['name'] }}</a>
                                </td>
                            
                                <td data-title="Price">
                                    <span class="">LKR {{ $items ['price'] }}.00</span>
                                </td>
                            
                                <td data-title="Quantity">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Quantity</span>
                                    <!-- <form class="mb-4" action="{{route('cart.update',$items->id)}}"> -->
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
                                             <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" name="quantity" type="text" value="{{$items->quantity}}">
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="col-auto pr-1">
                                                    <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <!-- </form> -->
                                </td>

                                 
                                                
                                        <!-- Quantity -->
                                        <!-- <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
                                            <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" name="quantity" type="number" value="{{$items->quantity}}">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-soft-secondary mb-3 mb-md-0 font-weight-normal px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto">Update cart</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-auto pr-1">
                                                    <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  -->
                                   
                                    <!-- End Quantity -->
                                </td>
                                
                                <td data-title="Total">
                                    <span class="">
                                    LKR  {{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($items->id)->getPriceSum()}}.00
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                
                                    <td>
                                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-soft-secondary mb-3 mb-md-0 font-weight-normal px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib text-primary fa-2x"></i></button>
                                         <a href="{{ route('cart.destroy', $items->id)}}" class="btn btn-soft-secondary mb-3 mb-md-0 font-weight-normal px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger fa-2x"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                               
                                <!-- <td>
                                    <div class="d-md-flex">
                                        <form class="mb-4" action="{{route('cart.update',$items->id)}}">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-soft-secondary mb-3 mb-md-0 font-weight-normal px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto">Update cart</button>
                                            <a href="../shop/checkout.html" class="btn btn-primary-dark-w ml-md-2 px-5 px-md-4 px-lg-5 w-100 w-md-auto d-none d-md-inline-block">Proceed to checkout</a>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </td> -->
                                </form>
                             </tr>
                         @endforeach
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index')->middleware('auth');;
Route::get('/cart/{cartItems}', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.add')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/cart/destroy/{itemId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/cart/update/{itemId}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/add-to-cart/{product}','CartController@addtocart')->name('addToCart');
```

Comment: when u r removing item from cart it should automatically  update total i guess as per doc . can u tell me what is happening

Comment: Actually, My requirement is when we increasing the quantity amount, the total price of that item also needs to be increased without an update button. It doesn't automatically update.

Comment: In my code if I change the quantity amount, then I should click the update button, then only the total amount is updating as per the quantity. @KamleshPaul

Comment: Are you saying that after making changes to the quantity form the form should automatically submit to the backend and generate the total price to show on the frontend?

Comment: @paudel yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not much idea about Laravel, but this solution in javascript will give you an idea how you can proceed...

```
function getPriceSum() {
    YOUR_ARRAY.reduce((sum, item) => { return sum + (item.price * item.quantity), 0 })
}
```

Comment: thank you, but my requirement is needed to be changed when we increasing or decreasing the quantity. For that how can I get that value without using buttons to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some codes:

1- Add a new route and method to retrieve all card items

```
Route::get('/cart/items', 'CartController@allItems')->name('cart.all-items')->middleware('auth');
```

method:

```
public function allItems()
    {
      return \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();
    }
```

2- next, you need to move and alter this block of code into Javascript and retrieve data from the above route by Ajax.

```
 @foreach(\Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent() as $items)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="{{ route('cart.destroy', $items->id)}}">x</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Product">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $items ['name'] }}</a
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Price">
                                        <span class="">LKR {{ $items ['price'] }}.00</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Quantity">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Quantity</span>
                                        <!-- Quantity -->
                                        <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
                                            <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" name="quantity" type="text" value="{{$items->quantity}}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-auto pr-1">
                                                    <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                        <!-- End Quantity -->
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Total">
                                        <span class="">
                                            {{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($items->id)->getPriceSum()}}
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                @endforeach
```

whenever a new product adds into your card or by an interval timer you can call the method of Javascript to get the latest products without refreshing the page.

Comment: if you need more about the javascript method, I can add more detail to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to forget Laravel and I do not have one near me, so this code below is just theoretical.

First of all, you need a backend to be able to update quantity on-the-fly. This is just your "normal" update, but it will return JSON with new `total`.

```php
public function updateQuantity($rowId)
{
    \Cart::session(auth()->id())->update($rowId, [
        'quantity' => [
        'relative' => true, 
        'value'=> request('quantity')
        ]
        ]);
    $newTotal = Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($items->id)->getPriceSum();
    return [ 'total' => $newTotal ];
}
```

New route for that:

```php
Route::get('/cart/updateQuantity/{itemId}', 'CartController@updateQuantity')->name('cart.updateQuantity')->middleware('auth');
```

Now we need to prepare frontend to be able to update `quantity` and `total` dynamically.

```html
<!-- we will change this line: -->
<input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" name="quantity" type="number" value="{{$items->quantity}}">
<!-- to this line: -->
<input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" name="quantity" id="quantity{{$items->id}}" data-id="{{$items->id}}" type="number" value="{{$items->quantity}}" onchange="updateQuantity({{$items->id}})">
<!-- yes, we just added ID to be able to use this later, and added callback -->
<!-- after previous line with "input" we can add an element to keep the route,
  this is because routes are calculated by Laravel dynamically -->
<span id="updateQuantityRoute{{$items->id}}" style="display:none">{{route('cart.updateQuantity',$items->id)}}</span>

<!-- also we need to prepare "total", so this line: -->
<span class="">{{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($items->id)->getPriceSum()}}</span>
<!-- change to this line: -->
<span class="" id="total{{$items->id}}">{{Cart::session(auth()->id())->get($items->id)->getPriceSum()}}</span>
```

So the magic is in `updateQuantity` function:

```js
function updateQuantity(itemId) {
  // here I will use jQuery just to show the idea
  const route = $('#updateQuantityRoute' + itemId);
  const newQuantity = $('#quantity' + itemId).val();
  $.post(route, {'quantity': newQuantity}).done(function( data ) {
    // here we have response
    if (typeof data === 'string') data = JSON.parse(data);
    const updatedTotal = data.total;
    $('#total' + itemId).innerText = updatedTotal; // update in DOM
  });
}
```